# I would like someone to help me with this error

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot( u_final %>% + ggplot(aes(x= fct_rev(sample), y = u00)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "deepskyblue1", alpha= 0.8) + 
coord_flip()+ labs(x= "sample", y= "isso aqui")+ theme_bw() )
```

Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ggplot( u_final, aes(x= fct_rev(sample), y = u00))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "deepskyblue1", alpha= 0.8)+ 
  coord_flip()+ 
  labs(x= "sample", y= "isso aqui")+ 
  theme_bw()
```

Assuming that `u_final` is your data frame, that will be what you pass into `ggplot`'s `data` parameter. But then you want a close parentheses. And then rest of your ggplot objects are strung together with `+` signs.